# In Objective-C, secondary import 'file not found' only when importing into test target. Builds otherwise

Tags: objective-c

I've got a class that imports `CompanyInternalDSKBaseClass` from an internal repo, not a pod (unfortunately). Things are building and running fine and have been for years.

MPMyClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass.h" // <-- 'CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass' file not found after importing MPMyClass.h into testing file

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MPMyClass : CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass

- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)str;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

MPMyClass.m

```
#import "MPMyClass.h"

@implementation MPMyClass {
    NSString *p_str;
}

- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)str {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        p_str = str;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

But, when I add a test target, testing scheme, and file, and try to run tests...

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "MPMyClass.h"

@interface MPMyClassTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation MPMyClassTests

- (void)test_zero {
    MPMyClass *myClass = [[MPMyClass alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
    XCTAssertNotNil(myClass);
}

@end
```

In `MPMyClass.h`, I'm getting `'CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass.h' file not found`.

- If I comment out `#import "MPMyClass.h"` in the test file, tests build and run fine.
- Switching to the main target, things build fine without any modification, so the import isn't *really* missing?
- I've cleaned the project, deleted derived data, and open and closed Xcode.
- This happens with any class I attempt to import into a test file that imports `CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass`.
- Importing files into the test target that do not have `#import CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass.h` works fine, and tests run fine also.
- Changing `"CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass.h"` to `<CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass/CompanyInternalSDKBaseClass.h>` yields 'file not found' also.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Test in Xcode is a different target. It might have the some header/library search paths missing which are provided in your main target. `I've got a class that imports CompanyInternalDSKBaseClass from an internal repo, not a pod (unfortunately)` - the centrepiece part of your MRE should be the configuration of your working target and the test target, you may want to [edit] the question and add this information